# Unbounded, Continuous Functions and Lebesgue Integrable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> For every continuous unbounded function $g$ on $(0,1)$ there exists an integrable nonnegative function $f$ such that $g \circ f$ is not integrable $(0,1)$.

I've been working on the above problem for a few days now without much progress. If $g(x)=1/x$, then $f(x) = x$ works. If $g(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$, then take $f(x) = x^2$, etc....My thought was to show that there exists an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such $g \circ f$ is not integrable with $f(x) = x^n$.
I'm not sure if this is true, however...I could use a hint.

Comment: Did you state this correctly? Given just that $g$ is a continuous function on $(0,1)$ and $f$ is non-negative the composition $g\circ f$ need not exist.

Comment: $g \circ f$ is only defined if $f$ takes values in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I copied the problem from a recent prelim; I just checked and what I wrote matches the prelim. I guess one should just interpret the problem in a way that makes sense, if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$ where $|g(x_n)| > 2^n$.  Define a function $f$ on $(0,1)$ so that $f(x) = x_n$ on $(2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n}]$.